# Android Spinner set custom adapter

Tags: java, android, json, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I'm working on an Android App (Too order objects) for school and I want to make a Spinner with categories labels.
However, when a label is selected, I want to get the selected category's id too.
I already can get my data into JSON thanks for my webservice but I don't know how to do to make my own custom adapter for my spinner.

The JSON looks like this :

```
[{"id":"1","name":"VEHICULES","subcategories":
[
    {"id":"1","name":"Voitures"},
    {"id":"2","name":"Motos"},
    {"id":"3","name":"Equipement auto"},
    {"id":"4","name":"Equipement moto"},
    {"id":"5","name":"Autres"}]
},
{"id":"2","name":"IMMOBILIER","subcategories":
[
    {"id":"6","name":"Locations"},
    {"id":"7","name":"Colocations"},
    {"id":"8","name":"Autres"}]
}]
```

Searching to make my own adapter, I created a java class Categories like that :

```
public class Categories {
    public int id;
    public String name;


    public Categories(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And, on my fragment I can get my JSON and read it :

```
public class AttemptCategories extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    String categoriesURL = "http:blabla.com";
    JSONArray dataJsonArr = null;
    JSONArray dataJsonArr2 = null;
    List<Categories> listCat = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0Z) {
        try {
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(categoriesURL);
            dataJsonArr = json.getJSONArray("categories");
            for (int i = 0; i < dataJsonArr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
                Categories cat = new  Categories(Integer.parseInt(c.getString("id")), c.getString("name"));
                listCat.add(cat);
                dataJsonArr2 =  c.getJSONArray("subcategories");
                for(int j = 0; j < dataJsonArr2.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject s = dataJsonArr2.getJSONObject(j);
                    Categories subcat = new  Categories(Integer.parseInt(s.getString("id")), s.getString("name"));
                    listCat.add(subcat);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) {
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 0, listCat);
        sCategories.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

When I try to load the page in which I want to see my spinner, my application crash... I tried it into debug mod but no exception appeared.

Does somebody know what is wrong or how can I resolve my problem please?

Comment: Please post your stack trace showing where your application crashes. For easier JSON parsing you might wanna check out the Retrofit library as well.

Comment: After, setting this adapter, the program use Looper.java, ActivityThread.java, AsyncTask.java and Handler.java and finally I read it on Debugger / Frames : 
uncaughtException():72, RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler (com.android.internal.os)